# Substituting a specific character at the end of words

Tags: python, regex, python-re

```
import re

text="Her sweet-natured father is constantly henpecked by his domineering wives, who rule their domains with iron fists. His wives were named Alexis, Eris, Irer, Zenith and Saunder."
text=re.sub(r'r$\b','rh',text)
print(text)
```

Desired output:

> Her sweet-natured fatherh is constantly henpecked by his domineering
> wives, who rule theirh domains with iron fists. His wives were named
> Alexis, Eris, Irerh, Zenith and Saunderh.

Output:

> Her sweet-natured father is constantly henpecked by his domineering
> wives, who rule their domains with iron fists. His wives were named
> Alexis, Eris, Irer, Zenith and Saunder.

I.e., no change has occurred in the string. Is something wrong?

Comment: Why is `"Her"` not affected in your desired output?

Comment: Test your regex in e.g. https://regex101.com/, the problem should be obvious from the description of it.

Comment: Also regex isn't appropriate here. Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: What is the `$` doing in the regex?

Comment: @ddejohn This is a part of a project I'm working on, not a homework assignment

Comment: Hi @MsBonniePython , have you seen my answer? I actually think it will help you.. please take a look at it if you didn't already, and give me some feedbacks. If it was helpful, I'll be so delighted if you give my answer an upvote  or even choose it as the correct answer ✅. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

1. Split the text with `white spaces` and `punctutations`.
2. Check all parts, if the last character is `r` or not.
3. If it was equal to `r`, add a character `h` to that part.
4. Join all parts together.

Check this code below:

```py
import re
text="Her sweet-natured father is constantly henpecked by his domineering wives, who rule their domains with iron fists. His wives were named Alexis, Eris, Irer, Zenith and Saunder."
parts = re.split("([\.\,\!\?\-\s+\_])", text)
for index, part in enumerate(parts):
    if len(part) != 0 and part[-1] == 'r':
       parts[index] += 'h'
final_text = "".join(parts[:])
print(final_text)
```

**Result**
Herh sweet-natured fatherh is constantly henpecked by his domineering wives, who rule theirh domains with iron fists. His wives were named Alexis, Eris, Irerh, Zenith and Saunderh.

Comment: Actually I want to replace only the r's at the end of a word, not all r's in the sentence.

Comment: I know that, my code is doing that ,too. It replaces the `r` s which have a space after it with `rh`s followed by a space. Try my code. It works.

Comment: It does not do what OP wants. You're missing instances where the end of a word is followed by `,` and `.`, for example. There are too many edge cases for this solution to be practical.

Comment: @MsBonniePython , I updated the answer.. please check it.

Comment: @ddejohn , I updated my answer. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use str.replace and `\b`:

```
text.replace(r'r\b',r'rh')
```

`\b` matches word boundary: that is either start of the word (`\W\w`) or end of the word (`\w\W`). So `r\b` capture any 'r' at end of any words.

```
text="Her sweet-natured father is constantly henpecked by his domineering wives, who rule their domains with iron fists. His wives were named Alexis, Eris, Irer, Zenith and Saunder."
result="Herh sweet-natured fatherh is constantly henpecked by his domineering wives, who rule theirh domains with iron fists. His wives were named Alexis, Eris, Irerh, Zenith and Saunderh."
```